# Object repository in xml file for Selenium WebDriver framework with Java and TestNG

Tags: xml, object, webdriver, repository

I am currently using Selenium WebDriver framework with Java and TestNG. I am using a property file to keep all my element locators by giving unique name for each element. How to use xml file to keep all my element locators and how to get those locators in my automation scripts?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XML as object repository like

```
<ObjRep>
<url>http://www.google.com</url>
<search_TxtFld>q</search_TxtFld>
<submt>btnG</submt>
</ObjRep>
```

And you can use the code for retrieve the objects from xml
below is the code:

```
public void objRepository(String eleName){
    try{
    File file=new File("F:\\Test.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db=dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc=db.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    //System.out.println("The node name is: "+doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());   

    NodeList nList=doc.getElementsByTagName("ObjRep");
    //System.out.println("The length is: "+nList.getLength());
    for(int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++){
        Node nNode=nList.item(i);
        if(nNode.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
          Element ele=(Element) nNode;
          System.out.println(ele.getElementsByTagName(eleName).item(i).getTextContent());
          }
    }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And you can use as

```
WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
d.get(objRepository(url));
d.findelement(by.name(objRepository(search_TxtFld)).sendkeys("test");
d.findelement(by.name(search_TxtFld(submt)).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a properties file to store the locators, can't you just use a Java interface to read the properties into variables and have the scripts reference the variables in the interface?

Comment: I have already using this. I want to use xml file instead of property file.